# Weirdness with the Image.FromStream "Parameter Not Valid"

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I had same problem couple of times but I was ignoring it, I was thinking that probably the image I am trying to load is somehow corrupted. This time I wanted to explore more.

So, first thing which crossed my mind is that maybe something is wrong with way how I am getting the image from the web with the C# WebClient. After a bit of trail and error and adjusting the proxy I have succeed loading the image with the :

```
 Image.FromStream(ms);
```

, "so then ..." I was thinking "Image is not the problem after all ..."
Next thing I've decided to do the simple thing, I have used

```
 File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\1\\bytes01.txt", imgData);
```

and I have saved the image to the disk.
Next, I've done the same thing from the Web Application expecting a different result.

But files were identical?!

Now I was confused, ok maybe something with the Web application?!

I have created another one, test Web application and from there everything was fine. WTF?!

Ok next I though maybe System.Drawing dll maybe wrong assembly ... but the assembly's were the same as well:

System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Bitmap))
{System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}

Next thing I have done is to use .Net Reflector, identifying the line of issue but I've got stack there:

```
num = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipLoadImageFromStream(new GPStream(stream), out zero);

[DllImport("gdiplus.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true)]
internal static extern int GdipLoadImageFromStream(UnsafeNativeMethods.IStream stream, out IntPtr image);
```

Just to mention in every application, code is identical:

```
 var imgData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\1\\bytes02.txt");
 var ms = new MemoryStream(imgData);
 ms.Write(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);
 ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
 ms.Position = 0;
```

In Console and Test Web application everything works as it should, in the Web Application where this code is located in the Referenced DLL, code does not work.

Just to mention this is a completely random image from the Net but I am posting this one as I have experienced this issue with this image.

http://vermin-explorers.co.uk/images/wetratflipped.gif

Build mode for all three is Any CPU.

Is there anyone who has any clue what is going on, and why this works in one case and not the other?

**Update 01:**

When Web Application running under the IIS GDI+ with tha particular image always fails. Why ? (Note: Reading the file is not the problem, it must be something with IIS permission on GDIPlus.dll ... how to allow this ?)

**Update 02:**

I have succeeded. I have make it work by changing the **Application Pool > Process Model > Identity > ApplicationPoolIdentity into Network Service**.
But this does not change fact that Exception which application throws does not have any sense whatsoever, I do not want to start about how much time I have lost ... so misleading ...
And I can bet that this same issue make other people think that something is wrong with Stream or Image format or who know what ... huuhhhh anyway ...